# Polynomial Least Squares for Image Curve Fitting

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, curve-fitting, least-squares

I am trying to fit a curve to a number of pixels in an image so I can do further processing regarding it's shape. Does anyone know how to implement a least squares method in C/++ preferably using the following parameters: an x array, a y array, and an answers array (the length of the answers array should tell how many coefficients need to be calculated)?

Comment: An exact solution for this is: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is not some exercise in implementing this yourself, I would suggest you use a ready-made library like [GNU gsl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/). Have a look at the functions whose names start with `gsl_multifit_`, see e.g. the second example [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Fitting-Examples.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am unsure of how to use gsl_multifit_, the examples seem to be for 3 dimensional data and I'm not sure how the covariance matrix works.

Comment: Do you have a solution that can be used in a commercial software without having to make source code available?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to fit ordered points (x,y) like in a graph you can use linear least squares methods but always with such methods you will need to specify the degree of the polynomial you use to approximate with (length of your answers array presumably). If your points are general ordered points in the plane that are able to form a closed loop or some outline of a structure (for example trying to fit points that describe an ellipse or a circle or other closed or more complex geometry) then you are going to need something more sophisticated. You can still use least squares but you will need to use a parametric type curve like a spline. Take a look at the pdf at this link which may give what you need (or at the very least illustrate what I am saying): http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffolk.uio.no%2Fin329%2Fnchap6.pdf&ei=Yp8CUNvHC8Kg0QX6r_mEBw&usg=AFQjCNHBUZ5t2Y7C8eONYSosRydLs4Zu4A

Without seeing an image of exactly what you are trying to fit it is hard to say - it is quite possible that your data can be fit in a non parametric way with linear least squares polynomials - if so all you will need is a linear algebra library and you can code the approximations yourself like so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares

Even so, all forms of approximation require you to decide on your form (function basis and degree etc) before you fit it. For example, if you want to decide on whether you need a 4th,5th,6th or 7th degree polynomial fit your data you would need to fit each one and assess the suitability for yourself. There is no generic way (at least none that I know of) that will tell you the degree of approximation you need to fit to your data.

Comment: Unfortunately I need polynomials in my least squares, and I've just come round to the fact that may data may actually be 3 dimensional as I will need to supply the least squares algorithm with the order the data is presented in. While the maths PDF is helpful, I'm not too good on the conversion between the maths and the C code.

Comment: Fitting a curve in 3D is a tough task. You will need to use orthogonal distance regression and parametric curves probably and this is far from trivial if you are coding it from scratch. Can you provide an image of the kind of data you have?

Comment: Well I am trying to create a general shape description (later for shape recognition), an example image could be a letter like so: http://tinypic.com/r/bcv45/6

Comment: @user293895 Yes I am afraid that there is no way you are going to be able to fit that using a polynomial. Splines or NURBS you would need for such a purpose. You just cannot do an x-y regression with that type of data you need parametric curves.