# Fit a circle or a spline into a bunch of 3D Points

Tags: c++, c, geometry, least-squares

I have some 3D Points that roughly, but clearly form a segment of a circle. I now have to determine the circle that fits best all the points. I think there has to be some sort of least squares best fit but I cant figure out how to start.
The points are sorted the way they would be situated on the circle. I also have an estimated curvature at each point.
I need the radius and the plane of the circle.
I have to work in c/c++ or use an extern script.

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Nope, just searched the net about least squares fitting circles. most that i found was in 2D though, so it didnt help.

Comment: You can port a 2D algorithm into 3D. You have **two** variables: the center of the circle and its radius. The center translates into three coordinates, so overall you want to optimize **four** variables (three coordinates and the radius) using least squares.

Comment: @alestanis actually, it's six real variables: the center and the circle's _normal vector_. — But that's not really a problem, what's more complicated is to generalise the definition of _distance of a point from a circle_ to 3d.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Can you explain? For me it's just `{x, y, z}` and `r`...

Comment: @alestanis: That only gives you circles that are aligned in one fixed predefined plane.

Comment: its six because if you port to 2D you still have to determine the plane in wich you calculate. that plane is determined by one of the 3d points and a normal vector, that has 3 variables.

Comment: I was thinking about a sphere, I got it now. Maybe there's an easy way to detect on which plane we are in a first step, rotate our coordinates and then find the circle in a second step using only two of the coordinates?

Comment: not so easy, cause you'd have to project the points on the x-y-plane (or y-z or x-z) -> there they would probably no longer form a circle.

Comment: @alestanis: that's a good idea; obviously you would _not_ use the xy, yz or zx plane but the actual plane where the circle lies in, or an approximation of it. Pedro's PCA suggestion is the way to go here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (PCA) to map your coordinates from three dimensions down to two dimensions.

Compute the PCA and project your data onto the first to principal components. You can then use any 2D algorithm to find the centre of the circle and its radius. Once these have been found/fitted, you can project the centre back into 3D coordinates.

Since your data is noisy, there will still be some data in the third dimension you squeezed out, but bear in mind that the PCA chooses this dimension such as to minimize the amount of data lost, i.e. by maximizing the amount of data that is represented in the first two components, so you should be safe.

Answer (score 3):

A good algorithm for such data fitting is [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) (Random sample consensus). You can find a good description in the link so this is just a short outline of the important parts:

In your special case the *model* would be the 3D circle. To build this up pick three random non-colinear points from your set, compute the hyperplane they are embedded in (cross product), project the random points to the plane and then apply the usual 2D circle fitting. With this you get the circle center, radius and the hyperplane equation. Now it's easy to check the support by each of the remaining points. The support may be expressed as the distance from the circle that consists of two parts: The orthogonal distance from the plane and the distance from the circle boundary inside the plane.

**Edit:** 
The reason because *i* would prefer RANSAC over ordinary Least-Squares(LS) is its superior stability in the case of heavy outliers. The following image is showing an example comparision of LS vs. RANSAC. While the ideal model line is created by RANSAC the dashed line is created by LS.[image]

Comment: This assumes that all points are in-plane, but the question refers to noisy data, so your solution will strongly depend on your choice of the initial three points.

Comment: No. What i've described is just _one_ run of RANSAC. The algorithm performs a lot of such runs and outputs the model with the best _support_ and therefore the circle that fits best to the noisy data. But that's descibed in the provided link.

Comment: Granted, but it still won't find the optimal solution in the least-squares sense if the resulting arc is not in a plane spanned by three of the sample points. Such a heuristic will very probably provide a *good* solution, but not necessarily the *best* one.

Comment: This is no heuristic. An arc in 3D is **by definition** embedded inside a plane :)

Comment: Yes, but you're missing the point: The RANSAC heuristic will only look at planes spanned by three points from the data set. That is a finite set of planes, and there is not guarantee that the plane of the *optimal* solution is in that set.

Comment: Of course. RANSAC will generate a circle (or arc) that goes _through_ at least 3 points. So the returned solution will only be optimal if the real circle is going trough these 3 points.

In contrary the LS approch will always return a solution that is optimal in accordance to the Least-Squares error, but you need to note that this ls-error itself is often not optimal in fitting a model into some noisy data samples(for example in case of heavy outliers)

Comment: There are definitely no heavy outliers in my data, so im gonna go with PCA. Thank you!

Comment: @AD-530: "Often not optimal" is far too broad a statement. Whether or not you use least-squares type fits depends on the types of errors you assume your data has, e.g. if it allows you to completely disqualify outliers or not.

Answer (score 1):

The arguably easiest algorithm is called Least-Square Curve Fitting.
You may want to check the [math](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html),
or look at similar questions, such as [polynomial least squares for image curve fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490912/polynomial-least-squares-for-image-curve-fitting)
However I'd rather use a library for doing it.

Comment: Do you happen to know such a library?

Comment: The answers to the SO question mention the GNU gsl.